# Why is difficult to unplug things from this electrical receptacle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

The electrical receptacle in my bathroom is difficult to use. It seems hard to unplug hair dryers etc. Do I need to replace it or can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to get the socket replaced rather than repaired - especially one that's in a bathroom as you might need to have a RCD socket to protect against shocks.

Sockets should have a certain degree of stiffness so that the plug doesn't just fall out or come partially out if you put even the slightest strain on the flex.

Answer (score 2):

Does it happen to be marked with TR (Tamper Resistant)? I find these outlets are more difficult to insert/remove plugs from.  That being said, it should not take significant amounts of force to use.

Is it just a specific hair dryer that is difficult to remove? If so you should inspect the prongs for damage.  If it is all plugs then the outlet is the problem.